# How to close/reopen tag inside of if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012

I can't figure out what is wrong with this razor code.

The IDE is telling me that my first `<ul>` doesn't have a matching end tag. It also says that the end tag doesn't have a matching beginning tag. It also doesn't recognize several lines as C# code and instead treats it as regular text.

The IDE complaints are in comments on the offending lines.

```
<div class="list-container">
    @{
        int i = 0;   

        <ul> //no matching ending tag
            @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            if (i % 8 == 0)
            {
        </ul> //no matching start tag
        <ul> //"Text is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for element ul"
            } //IDE doesn't recognize this closing brace as code... see it as text

        <li>@item.ContentItem.Title.Value</li>

            i++; //IDE doesn't recognize this closing brace as code... see it as text
        } //IDE doesn't recognize this closing brace as code... see it as text
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

When the view is executed, I get the compilation error you'd expect when you leave off a `}`: "The code block is missing a closing "}" character. "

As soon as I remove the `</ul><ul>` from inside the `if` statement, the view compiles and executes.

What's interesting is when I click on one of the `ul` tags, the correct starting or ending tag is also highlighted.

Clearly I've done something wrong. Am I not using Razor correctly?

Comment: You have opened two code blocks (`foreach` and `if`) and didn't close them before your closing `</ul>` tag. So the closing `</ul>` tag has no opening tag within the same code block that started with `if(i % 8 == 0)`.

Comment: Perhaps the ul tags would work better outside the razor code entirely? Try putting them right next to the div tags.

Comment: I won't put this as an answer because I don't know EXACTLY, but some HTML tags don't allow code to work properly inside of them. I've run into this problem quite a few times using Razor recently. If anyone has a good reference/solution for this, that would be awesome! All I ended up doing was changing which tags I used. I don't remember which, exactly.

Also: I believe scope matters as well. The fact that you're trying to close your <ul> tag in a different scope than the previous one might have something to do with it as well.

Comment: I've changed title what I think reflects the problem better. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, that's better. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `@:` to [explicitly define content](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx). The following does not give compile errors on my system:

```
<div class="list-container">
    @{
        int i = 0;   

        @:<ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            if (i % 8 == 0)
            {
        @:</ul>
        @:<ul>
            }

        <li>@item.ContentItem.Title.Value</li>

            i++;
        }
        @:</ul>
    }
</div>
```

Note: You also have incorrect comment syntax in your post, but I'm assuming that was just for the SO example.

Answer (score 3):

You have C#/Razor code blocks and HTML (open/close tag) blocks intersecting and that's why you get the error.

If I'm correct, and you want to display all the items in groups/lists of 8 items, you probably want something like this:

```
<div class="list-container">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i = i + 8)
    {
        <ul>
            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                <li>Model.Items[i+j].ContentItem.Title.Value</li>                        
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

I didn't test this, as I don't have your model, but it should work at least with minimal adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to emit a list item for every 8th element in the model...  You need to emit the parent element - in this case the UL, and then worry about the LI elements, like below.  I think the editor is barfing b/c you're opening and closing your UL and you had a curly brace in the wrong place around your LI

```
<div class="list-container">
    <ul>
      @{
        int i = 0;   
        foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
          if (i%8 == 0)
          {
            <li>@item.ContentItem.Title.Value</li>
          }
          i++; 
        } 
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
```